# publish to kafka topic within a map method

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, kafka-producer-api

Writing to kafka topic from within a map function (SCALA) ?

1. Reading from a kafka topic in a **FLINK** Application
2. Processing the data within a map function
3. **Problem Statement** - Within the map function I am looping through a list. For each element in the list I want to publish to a kafka topic.
4. when I get the output from the map and sink it works, but if I try a push to topic from within map method it doesn't
5. Is it possible to publish to topic from within a map method

   ```
   // Main Function
   def main(args: Array[String]) {

   ...
   // some list
   val list_ = ("a", "b", "c", "d")
   // Setup Properties
   val props = new Properties()
   props.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", zookeeper_url + ":" + zookeeper_port)
   props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", broker_url + ":" + broker_port)
   props.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
   props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
   props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")

   ...

   // Connect to Source
   val input_stream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09[String](topic_in, new SimpleStringSchema(), properties))

   // Process each Record
   val stream = input_stream.map(x=> {        

     // loop through list "list_" -> variable in in Main
     // and publish to topic_out
     // -- THIS IS MY CURRENT ISSUE !!!)
     // -- Does not work (No compile issue)
     // 
     var producer2 = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
     var record    = new ProducerRecord(topic_out, "KEY", list(i))
     producer2.send(record)
     producer2.flush()

    // ... Other process and return processed string

   })

   // publish to different topic of proccessed input string (Works)
   stream.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer09[String](broker_url + ":" + broker_port, other_topic, new SimpleStringSchema()))
   ```

Comment: What "does not work"? Why are you creating the producer in the loop??? What's the deal with all the `vars`? What's `i`????
Why are you using different producer classes inside and outside the `map`?

Comment: "does not work" - When I submit the job to flink. it runs the job but it seams it does not go into the map function (if the producer code is included)"

Comment: I'm trying to loop through a list based a some condition from the input stream and post to a topic the item of interest

Comment: How would I go about doing this? (Your assistance is appreciated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not make a kafka producer inside of a map function and do not try to write to a kafka topic inside of a map. Honestly, I can't quote anything saying it's a bad idea...but it is a bad idea.

Instead. change your map function to a flatMap (see the first example here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/datastream_api.html).

So in your loop, instead of making a kafka producer every loop, you just do `collector.collect(recordToPublishToKafka)`.

And your sink will publish each out as they are collected.

Comment: Thank you, that helps. I agree with you (I'm still learning the Flink/Kafka tool set, hence the bad idea... ) will take your advice. Many Thanks and Regards